# I am having trouble returning a String after I use a for loop and switch statement to modify it

Tags: java, loops, switch-statement

```
  public static String octalEquivalent(String binaryInput) {

    String octalOutput =" ";
    for(int counter=binaryInput.length(); counter<3; counter++)
    {
        binaryInput= "0"+binaryInput;
    }
    for(int counter=binaryInput.length(); counter%3==1; counter++)
    {
        binaryInput= "0"+binaryInput;
    }
    for (int counter1=0, counter2=3; counter2<=binaryInput.length(); counter1+= 3, counter2+=3)
    {


        String temp=binaryInput.substring(counter1,counter2);
        switch (temp){
        case "000": octalOutput = octalOutput+"0";
        break;
        case "001": octalOutput = octalOutput+"1";
        break;
        case "010": octalOutput = octalOutput+"2";
        break;
        case "011": octalOutput = octalOutput+"3";
        break;
        case "100": octalOutput = octalOutput+"4";
        break;
        case "101": octalOutput = octalOutput+"5";
        break;
        case "110": octalOutput = octalOutput+"6";
        break;
        case "111": octalOutput = octalOutput+"7";
        break;
        }
    }


    return(octalOutput);        
}
```

in the first two for loops I added a space after the 0 which made it not match up to the switch statement's cases. example binaryInput= "0 "+binaryInput;
instead of binaryInput= "0"+binaryInput;

it still doesn't return the right answer but at least it is returning something.

Comment: What is the purpose of the second for?

Comment: Did Java 1.8 allow `String` as an argument for `switch` statements?

Comment: Java 1.8 (or maybe an earlier one) added strings to switches.

Comment: I doubt the problem is with the returning. Most likely you're *not* modifying `octalOutput` because of some other problem.

Comment: @erhun the second for loop is to get the binary number to be divisible by 3 so I can take sections of it in 3's to convert it to octal in the 3rd for loop.

Comment: @immibis I am thinking the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's something I'm missing, I'd recommend [`Integer.parseInt(String, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) to convert the binary input into a number, and then [`Integer.toOctalString(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toOctalString%28int%29) to convert that to an octal `String`. Something like

```
public static String octalEquivalent(String binaryInput) {
    return Integer.toOctalString(Integer.parseInt(binaryInput, 2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is counter2 ever greater than binaryInput.Length? If no, then there is your answer. That for loop is never getting hit, so your string is never changing.

Also, it looks like all you really want to do is substring the binaryInput between 0 and 3, which wouldn't require a for-loop at all. Try something like this, perhaps:

```
String temp="";
    temp=binaryInput.substring(0,3);
    switch (temp){
    case "000": octalOutput = octalOutput+"0";
    break;
    case "001": octalOutput = octalOutput+"1";
    break;
    case "010": octalOutput = octalOutput+"2";
    break;
    case "011": octalOutput = octalOutput+"3";
    break;
    case "100": octalOutput = octalOutput+"4";
    break;
    case "101": octalOutput = octalOutput+"5";
    break;
    case "110": octalOutput = octalOutput+"6";
    break;
    case "111": octalOutput = octalOutput+"7";
    break;
    }
```

Comment: This is not an answer it should be comment

Comment: Expanded on my original answer. I feel like this is sufficient enough to get him headed in the right direction.

Comment: I see what you mean @iByrd92. I modified my code and am still not getting the proper return.

Comment: I am trying to be able to modify any length of a binary digit. Meaning I want the code to be able to convert a binary number such as 01101011011 to octal as well. That is why I have the for loop and that is what the two for loops preceding the third loops are for as well. They are there so I can get the binary to be divisible by 3 so that the 3rd for loop will work properly.

Comment: @GraysonWood, are you aware that you also are resetting the length variable between for loops? Also, on your third for loop it seems like it would be better for counter2 to be <= binaryInput.length(), as opposed to > than it. 

Reason being, if it IS a number like 01101011011 then it will no way have a length of less than 3, which counter2 starts at.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String octalEquivalent(String binaryInput) {

    String octalOutput =" ";
    for(int counter=binaryInput.length(); counter<3; counter++)
    {
        binaryInput= "0"+binaryInput;
    }

    while(binaryInput.length()%3 != 0)
    {
        binaryInput= "0"+binaryInput;
    }
    for (int counter1=0, counter2=3; counter2<=binaryInput.length(); counter1+= 3, counter2+=3)
    {


        String temp=binaryInput.substring(counter1,counter2);
        switch (temp){
        case "000": octalOutput = octalOutput+"0";
        break;
        case "001": octalOutput = octalOutput+"1";
        break;
        case "010": octalOutput = octalOutput+"2";
        break;
        case "011": octalOutput = octalOutput+"3";
        break;
        case "100": octalOutput = octalOutput+"4";
        break;
        case "101": octalOutput = octalOutput+"5";
        break;
        case "110": octalOutput = octalOutput+"6";
        break;
        case "111": octalOutput = octalOutput+"7";
        break;
        }
    }


    return(octalOutput);        
}
```

I did it!